# How to apply aggregate functions to results of other aggregate functions in single query?

Tags: sql, aggregate

I have a table `BIKE_TABLE` containing columns `Rented_Bike_Count`, `Hour`, and `Season`. My goal is to determine average hourly rental count per season, as well as the `MIN`, `MAX`, and `STDDEV` of the average hourly rental count per season. I need to do this in a single query.

I used:

```
SELECT 
    SEASONS,
    HOUR,
    ROUND(AVG(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT),2) AS AVG_RENTALS_PER_HR
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY HOUR, SEASONS
ORDER BY SEASONS
```

and this gets me close, returning 96 rows (4 seasons x 24 hours per) like:

| SEASON | HOUR | AVG_RENTALS_PER_HR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Autumn | 0 | 709.44 |
| Autumn | 1 | 552.5 |
| Autumn | 2 | 377.48 |
| Autumn | 3 | 256.55 |

But I cannot figure out how to return the following results that use `ROUND(AVG(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT)` as their basis:

1. What is the average hourly rental count per season? The answer should be four lines, like: Autumn, [avg. number of bikes rented per hour]
2. What is the `MIN` of the average hourly rental count per season?
3. Same for `MAX`
4. Same for `STDDEV`.

I tried running

```
MIN(AVG(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT)) AS MIN_AVG_HRLY_RENTALS_BY_SEASON,
MAX(AVG(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT)) AS MAX_AVG_HRLY_RENTALS_BY_SEASON,
STDDEV(AVG(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT)) AS STNDRD_DEV_AVG_HRLY_RENTALS_BY_SEASON
```

as nested SELECT and then as nested FROM clauses, but I cannot seem to get it right. Am I close? Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please give your table definition and some sample data, ideally as a DBfiddle if not as text

Comment: Forgive me, Kendle, but what further definition would be helpful here? If you are asking for sample data from the original `Bike_Table`, it has columns: SEASON [Autumn, Summer, Winter, or Spring], HOUR [0-23], and BIKE_RENTAL_COUNT [integers]. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are over complicating the task. Does this give you your answers? If not please tell me the difference between it's output and your desired output.
Of course you can add `ROUND()` to reach column etc as you see fit.

```
SELECT 
    SEASONS,
    MIN(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT) minimum,
    MAX(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT) maximum,
    STDDEV(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT) sDev,
    AVG(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT) average
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY SEASONS
ORDER BY SEASONS;
```

According to your comment It seems that you may want the following query.

```
WITH seasons AS(
  SELECT 
    Season,
    AVG(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT) seasonAverage
  FROM TABLE
  GROUP BY season)
SELECT
  AVG(seasonAverage) average,
  MIN(seasonAverage) minimum,
  MAX(seasonAverage) maximum,
  STDDEV(seasonAverage) sDev
FROM
  seasons;
```

Comment: It may well be that I am over-complicating the task! Regarding your solution, though: I need *first* to calculate `AVG(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT)` and then determine the max/min/sDev of *that* result, but your solution will calculate the min/max/sDev of `RENTED_BIKE_COUNT` (that is, the non-averaged column), right?

Comment: Do you want the min,max,AVG&STDDEV of the average of each season?

Comment: Yes, I need those for each season.

Comment: My first query gives the min,max,AVG abd STDDEV for each of the 4 seasons. The second starts with the AVG of each season and gives the min,max,AVG and STDDEV of the 4.

Comment: Kendle, let me first say that I am grateful for your help. Your top query, however, returns the "SELECT list expression references column HOUR which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [3:5]" error.